# Copy protection in free apps for Android

Tags: java, android, security, copy

Is there any reason for activating the copy protection in a free application?

Is the .apk more vulnerable to attacks that try to guess the internal mechanism of the application when the copy protection is off?

I'm using ProGuard in my apk.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Code protection is useless and obsolete. Anyhow, using obfuscation as you do is already a good strategy. LVL provides a good solution to prevent unauthorized / unlicenced use of an app...but it is only available to paying apps.

*However*, You could have a look at the authorisation librairy for android. Although we didn't have much time to dedicate to it, it works well and provide a way to "sell" a free app on android market but with limited features and a seperate paying unlocker.

http://code.google.com/p/android-authorization-library/updates/list

Regards, 
 Stéphane

Answer (score 1):

Copy protection will be going away for all apps and the new way to go is the [Licensing Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html).  This is not available for Free Apps though, and you'll have to implement your own protection if need be